# Entity Framework 7 table-valued Functions support

Tags: entity-framework

I'm developing a project with MVC 6 and EF 7. I need to use geolocation to get nearest shop from the client. I've read that spatial data is not yet available in EF 7. So I thought that I could use as an alternative a table valued function like this:

```
   ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPuzzle]
(   
    @lat float,
    @long float
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT city, ROUND(Location.STDistance(geography::Point(@lat, @long, 4326)) / 1000, 0) km FROM Shop
    WHERE Location.STDistance(geography::Point(@lat, @long, 4326)) / 1000 < 20
)
```

But I don't know (if it is possible) how to call db functions with EF7. I've already tried with some example relative to EF6 but it doesn't work...

Any other idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859577) for a walk-through on adding a TVF to an EF6 Model using Database First. The benefit is the ability to use the TVF like a table in your Linq queries. The drawback is the special handling to create the Model. Sometimes it is easiest to make changes to an EF6 model by updating the database, deleting the model, and then regenerate it from the database.  But with this approach, additional manual steps would have to be performed on the model each time.